# How to overcome query strings errors on thumb.php?src=image.jpg&w=xx&h=xx through W3C validation?

Tags: php, html, validation

When i validate my page, I am getting the following error, and almost 50 error or this..

"**An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images.**"

The HTML code is as follows:
`<img class="photo" src="thumb.php?src=thephoto.jpg&amp;w=100&amp;h=75" alt="Paradesi beating the records">`

By putting `&amp;` resolves the validation issue, but the thumb.php doesn't work afterwards. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is almost certainly wrong: `src="thumb.php?src=thephoto.jpg&amp;` what is that URL doing exactly?

Comment: [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) may be of help

Comment: `&amp;` is the correct way to represent an `&` in HTML, including within URLs.

Comment: The thumb.php is not taking in the query strings properly. For example, if its 'thumb.php?src=pic&amp;h=200', the query keys would be `src=pic, amp;h=200.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. `&amp;` will be automatically converted by the browser. The issue is that you are duplicating `src=` in there, that can't be right.

Comment: Sorry the second `src` is an argument to be passed via the get method to the file thumb.php. Hold, I'll get you the var_dump from the thumb.php, that might be helpful.

Comment: mmm seems like the file is working now. It must've been some typos I made before. Thanks guys